# Transition property doesn't apply

Tags: css, css-transitions

[On my page](http://baiadesign.com/demo/demo18/#), clicking on a link brings a menu to the screen while pushing the page to make room for the menu. It's all animated with `transition` CSS property. For some reason though, some elements get correctly animated while others don't: specifically, the top bar gets no animation at all. Can anybody tell me why?

**CSS**

```
#top_menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
#mobile_menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: -280px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;

}
.left_0 {
    left: 0 !important;
}
.left_280 {
    left: 280px !important;
}
.left_minus_280 {
    left: -280px !important;
}
body,
.wrap,
#mobile_menu,
#top_menu {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='mobile_menu'>
    mobile menu
  </div>
  <div id='top_menu'>
    <a href='#'>menu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( '#top_menu a' ).click(function() {
  $( "#mobile_menu, #top_menu, #wrap" ).removeClass();
  if( $('#mobile_menu').css('left') == '-280px' ) { 
    $( "#mobile_menu" ).addClass( 'left_0' );           
    $( "#top_menu" ).addClass( 'left_280' );  
    $( ".wrap" ).addClass( 'left_280' );  
  }
  else { 
    $( "#mobile_menu" ).addClass( 'left_minus_280' ); 
    $( "#top_menu" ).addClass( 'left_0' );  
    $( ".wrap" ).addClass( 'left_0' );            
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `left: 0` in `#top_menu`.

It'll set the left edge of the top_menu to the right of the right edge of its nearest positioned ancestor `#mobile_menu`. So they will make a transition together.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine, you just missed `left 0` to add in `#top_menu`.

```
#top_menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
}
```